# Jquery select all except next sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to select all `<dd>` siblings except for the immediate one, but this doesn't work.. I tried many ways... Please advice me on what's the correct way to go about this.

```
$(function(){
    //hide all dds
    $("dd:not(:first)").hide();
    $("dt").click(function(){

        //slide up all dds except for the next
        $(this).siblings("dd").not(this.next()).slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown("nomral");

    });
});
```

another way I tried is:

```
$(this).siblings("dd:not(first)").slideUp();
```

which did not work either.. I want to implement this only using jquery, with no additional libraries... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `this` to jQuery:

```
$(this).siblings("dd").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not start by selecting the next element and then getting *its* siblings? That would give you all the dd elements except for the next one.

```
$(this).next().siblings("dd").slideUp();
```

If you also want to slide down the next one you could do it all with one long (chained) line:

```
$(this).next().slideDown().siblings("dd").slideUp();
```

As far as your original code, the following line would give you an error:

```
$(this).siblings("dd").not(this.next()).slideUp();
```

...because `this.next()` is trying to call a method that `this` doesn't have. It'd need to be `$(this).next()`:

```
$(this).siblings("dd").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
```